# Why are some script tags skipped when adding nonces for content security policy in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, nonce, content-security-policy

I am working on wordpress site and I am trying to add nonce to all the scripts, below is the code that I am using it works fine for most of the tags but it seems to skip some of the scripts tags. One of the script tage is auto generated by wordpress that one is also skipped

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'wp_script_tag_nonce', 10, 3 );
function wp_script_tag_nonce( $tag, $handle ) {
  
        $nonce = TPJ_NONCE; // Or whatever your nonce value should be

        $tag = str_replace( '<script ', "<script nonce='$nonce'", $tag );


    return $tag;
}
```

images of the error and scripts that are skipped

[as you can see most of the scripts have the nonce but the  doe not have the nonce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ge7M9.png)
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kPUj.png)

I have tried to use the wp_enqueue_scripts but it does not allow to modify the script tag.

Answer (score 0):

The [`script_loader_tag` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/script_loader_tag/) only applies to tags that load JavaScript files, not inline JavaScript blocks. When last I looked (about one month ago) there is not a filter for inline scripts added via [`wp_add_inline_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/), so for my site, I had to add `unsafe-inline` to the `script-src` CSP directive to allow inline scripts to work.

Source:
https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3d1140c8988bb42a01c15a483aaa5fb22c80f1a9/wp-includes/class-wp-scripts.php#L230